# A massive slider starts from rest from a point S (which is at the same height as a point T at the top of the track)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

This is a question from previous physics aptitude test.

A massive slider starts from rest from a point S (which is at the same height
as a point T at the top of the track) and slides along a frictionless circular
track as sketched in figure below. The slider

[image]

A does not get to T.

B gets to T and falls straight down.

C gets to T but then, leaves the track and falls down following a parabola
trajectory to the left.

D passes T staying on the track all the way through.

I found 2 different reasoning for this question one is B just conservation of energy and the other is A since velocity will just keep decreasing until it falls of circular motion  .

Can anyone help by a detailed reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To arrive at T, the object needs to have sufficient velocity in the last moments before it gets there to remain stuck to the track - what velocity is needed to overcome the pull of gravity.

But it must have zero velocity when it gets there because it runs out of potential energy.

Can you see how those two statements get you to the answer?

Comment: I think The slider cannot maintain circular motion at up to T since v^2 < Rg but then what about conservation o energy suggesting that the slider should just reach T and fall straight down .

Comment: Not - to reach T it would need to have horizontal velocity. It does not have enough energy to maintain the velocity necessary to stay on the rail. You can calculate the point at which the velocity (which is a function of height) is not sufficient to make contact.

Comment: Perhaps this makes it clear: if you have a "ski jump" type of track, you will NOT reach the height where you started during your parabolic track after take-off, since part of your potential energy is converted to horizontal kinetic energy. That leaves less vertical velocity available. The same thing, but in a more convoluted manner, is true here.

Comment: Now it is much clearer , Thank you for illumination .